# Why is my bike making a grinding and clicking noise?

Tags: clicking, shimano-di2, grx

I recently received my new Canyon Grizl CF SLX 8 with a GRX Di2 2x11 groupset. Fresh out of the box I put it in my stand to go through the gears. I immediately noticed a constant clicking noise like when the gears aren't properly adjusted. I also noticed that the bike makes a grinding noise, even at low load, which gets louder at high load and in the highest gears (i.e. the smallest cogs). The grinding can also be felt in the pedals and is best described as the feeling when a wheel rubs against the frame. Here is a video of the issue:

https://youtube.com/shorts/482UhaoJXFw

I have gone through several steps:

1. Indexing the shifting manually (i.e. not using the e-Tube app).
2. Adjusting the limit screws
3. Adjusting the B-screw
4. Replaced the derailleur hanger
5. The chain is not rubbing against the front derailleur
6. The wheel is not rubbing against the frame
7. The cassette is tightened
8. Removed the chain from the chainring and rotated the crank arms - bearings seems to run smoothly.

Admittedly this is my first time running a Di2 setup, but the gearshift itself works perfectly. I consider myself a somewhat skilled mechanic and have always fixed my bikes myself and I have never experienced this problem before. I can't figure out what the next step is. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: @davidw yeah seems the SE backend can't in-line a short vs a regular video.  There's a bug report at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385316/on-sites-allowing-youtube-embeds-allow-embedding-youtube-shorts-as-well-as-norm  but its not got any traction.

Comment: @Criggie I wasn't sure if that was me or not; that short won't even play properly for me in YouTube itself.  Stupid Google; a couple more weeks and I'll be finished ditching Chrome completely.  If they can't even make YouTube work properly on Chrome, I'm done with it.

Answer (score 3):

The Graunching noise seems to be in-time with the crank rotations, and appears when the right-side crankarm is at the ~2 o'clock position, not the 8 o'clock.

That implies to me that the chain or chainring is rubbing on something but only for less than 10% of the full revolution.

My suspicion would be the FD cage, and that the chainring is not flat.  Get in real close, mind you don't catch hair/clothes/fingers in the chain, and see if tweaking the Front Derailleur helps at all.  I'd even try putting some kind of indicator on the chainring to measure runout in the horizontal.  You might even see something placing a straightedge (like a metal ruler)  across the chainring and look for deviation.   Teeth that are subtly bent out may be showing wear, but marking up suspect areas with permanent marker (Sharpie) can help too.

Good luck !

As for the clicking I have no useful suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The noise definitely seems to appear systematically at around the 2 o'clock position. I hadn't noticed that - so thanks for that. I suppose that rules out certain sources such as the bearings? 
And thanks for the suggestion regarding the chainring - I will look more into that. I have also inspected the motion of the chain some more and there clearly seems to be an instability in the movement which could indicate an uneven chainring. 
I will update the post if I find a solution.